# Why is there a different output for counting each element in an array?

Tags: javascript

In the code below if `count[item]` is truthy increment it else set it's initial value to 1
however I don't understand why when I give the property `a` string value other than 0 (of course) the final result is `a:2`

```
const letters = ["a", "b", "a", "b", "c", "d", "a"];

let count = {"a": 0}; // 0 or "0"

letters.forEach(function (item){
   if (count[item]){
    count[item]++
   }else {
    count[item] = 1
   }
})

console.log(count)
// result
a: 3
b: 2
c: 1
d: 1
```

now the result here is different

```
let count = {"a": "asdasd"}; // or any other string

letters.forEach(function (item){
   if (count[item]){
    count[item]++
   }else {
    count[item] = 1
   }
})

// result

a: 2
b: 2
c: 1
d: 1
```

Can please someone explain?

Comment: In your first example, the initial value of `count["a"]` is set to a number `0`, so the increment operation works as expected.

In your second example, the initial value of `count["a"]` is set to a string `"asdasd"`, which cannot be converted to a valid number. When the increment operation is applied to this string, the result is **[`NaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN)**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you insert an arbitrary string in there, you end up doing this:

```
count['a']++  // "asdasd"++
```

This will result in:

```
{a: NaN}
```

Because you can't increment a string. The next time the letter `a` is encountered in `letters` though, the `if` checks the following:

```
if (count['a']) {  // if (NaN) {
```

Since NaN is falsey, that check is false, and the NaN is overwritten by 1 due to `count['a'] = 1`. That means the first increment was lost, so the final count is one less than it should be.